# CSS - How to use transitions to move smoothly an item when another appears so it changes the layout

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have two drop down buttons in a nav bar. Currently, when I hover the left button, the right button moves instantly to the right to let space for the drop down to appear. What I want is to let it slides smoothly to the right, not instantaneously.

I tried to apply "transition: 1s" but it requires a start and end value, and since the width property don't change, the only thing changing is the display property (that hides the menu). How should I do it? I don't want to use transform property... Have a nice day :)

```css
        nav {
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .nav_item>button {
            border: none;
        }

        .dropdown_item {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown_content {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .nav_item:hover .hidden {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <button>File</button>
        <div class="hidden">
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Save map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Load new map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Another</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <button>File</button>
        <div class="hidden">
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Save map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Load new map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Another</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You set ```display:none;``` and ```display:block;```, so it's usually not make an animation, try to add ```transition``` then set the ```opacity:``` to **0** and **1**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to try and animate the display property, but that being said, there are some clever people out there and some hacks you can do:

```css
        
        nav {
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .nav_item>button {
            border: none;
        }

        .dropdown_item {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown_content {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .hidden {
            animation: show .2s;
            display: none;
        }

        .nav_item:hover .hidden {
            display: block;
        }

        @keyframes show {
            from { width: 0; }
            to { width: 100px; }
        }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <button>File</button>
        <div class="hidden">
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Save map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Load new map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Another</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <button>File</button>
        <div class="hidden">
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Save map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Load new map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Another</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The above was inspired by [CSS Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/so-youd-like-to-animate-the-display-property/) about animating display properties.

I believe this achieves the desired effect from your initial question.

That being said, I'd suggest taking a far simpler (and cleaner) route by simply adding `position: absolute` into the `.dropdown_content` class:

```css
        
        nav {
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .nav_item>button {
            border: none;
        }

        .dropdown_item {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown_content {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .nav_item:hover .hidden {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <button>File</button>
        <div class="hidden">
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Save map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Load new map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Another</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <button>File</button>
        <div class="hidden">
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Save map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Load new map</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown_item">Another</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This removes all width dependancy from the equation and makes the user experience more predictable.

I hope this helps.